# How to get rid of DuckDuckgo browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Since a couple of days ago I cannot use Tor for browsing because DuckDuckgo browser automatically replaces Tor when I start browsing.

Comment: What happened before? Could you describe a bit more in detail what you expect to happen?

Comment: Nothing happens before. I started Tor as usual typing keywords to search for. And then DuckDuckgo page appeared. I started Tor for several times but in no avail – DuckDuckgo page appears each time so that I finally gave up.

Answer (score 7):

When you type a search term into either the URL bar or the search box, the search term is passed by the browser to a search engine. The Tor Browser doesn't perform the search itself.

DuckDuckGo is currently the default search engine. (There's a level of indirection here as the Tor Browser uses disconnect.me as an intermediary.)

If you want to change the search engine:

- Click on the search box in the top right, which will drop down a menu;
- Click "Change Search Settings";
- Pick a search engine from the Default Search Engine drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution. Using Tor menu, select preferences or settings, depending on your operating system. Now open Search settings.

You have many options here. Start with option Default Search Engine. If You don't like Ducky, remove it. But don't forget that you can also add/remove and check/uncheck search engines used to acquire search results. For example, Ducky is sort of classy. You can dress him up as DuckDuckGo - TOR. Which is very different than old-fashioned DuckDuckGo. Oh, and you mght also want to uncheck Disconnect. It used to be a great service. Following reports to enforcement on not-so-great sites, those onions get blocked by Darpa Services, but Disconnect couldn't care less about up dating. Which leaves you super disconnected with endless annoying Akamai Cloudflare spam results.

Other topic? Who does not wish any Tor search would filter out Cloudflare and equally annoying Turkey Military. Anyway, just use your Search settings to customize your Tor Search experience. If you can't access those settings, uninstall and reinstall the Tor bundle. Easy.